# onOptionsItemsSelected not being used in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-listfragment

I'm trying to add a button to my menu bar in my ListFragment class. When I click the button, nothing happens though. The `onCreateOptionsMenu` method is never being called in the class. I've tried everything to get it working but it still won't work. Has anyone got any solutions?

I've attached my code below:

```
public class FragmentZero extends ListFragment {
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);

        // use your custom layout
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout_zero, container, false);

        oslist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        new JSONParse().execute();
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_fragment_zero, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemsSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Take appropriate action for each action item click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_refresh:
                // check for updates action
                RefreshButton();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Post the onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) of your Activity

Comment: Hi Gabriele, I'm not sure how the activity would affect this problem as this has got to do with my Fragment class. but when i added `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` to my MainActivity ,I still got the `method is never used` message. I assume my problem lies in my FragmentZero class above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` to your `onCreateView()` method and remove it in `OnCreate()`.

Comment: My `onOptionsItemsSelected` isn't being run now. Can you see any error?

Comment: Your are using ActionBar, try `onMenuItemSelected`

Comment: `onMenuItemSelected` is also not being used. I'm guess this has got to do with me extending ListFragment.

Answer (score 0):

So this was a pretty stupid error that I was having and I solved it thanks to everyone's help here.

I was spelling `onOptionItemSelected` wrong. I was adding an extra 's' after item.

As soon as I corrected this, the method started to work.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_refresh:
            RefreshButton();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

private void RefreshButton() {
    oslist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    new JSONParse().execute();
}
```